# Foreach over multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have two arrays, I want to print values from both, if the key is present in $array_two

**example code** :

```
$array_one = [
    'one' => 'foo',
    'two' => 'bar'
];

$array_two = [
    'one' => 'view_foo',
];
```

I use this code

```
foreach($array_one as $array_key_one => $val_array_one)
{
    foreach($array_two as $array_key_two => $val_array_two)
    {
        if($array_key_one == $array_key_two)
        {
            echo $val_array_two;
        }
        else
        {
            echo $val_array_one;
        }
    }
}
```

But i want to use only one ***foreach***

**The desired results**

*bar, view_foo*

How to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if:

```
foreach($array_one as $array_key_one => $val_array_one)
{
    if(isset($array_two[$array_key_one] ))
    {
       echo $array_two[$array_key_one];
    }
    else
    {
       echo $val_array_one;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could *intersect* the array keys and then iterate over the results:

```
foreach (array_intersect_key($array1, $array2) as $key => $value1) {
    echo $value1, ' ', $array2[$key], ' ' ;
}
```

> [array_intersect_key](http://php.net/array_intersect_key) returns an array containing all the entries of array1which have keys that are present in all the arguments.